# ufw & iptables don't block incoming connection

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

I enable ufw and I tried to block all the traffic from one server, but I can't.

It only blocks ssh, all the other ports are open. I test it with telnet.

I want to allow all ports for some IPs, and block all ports if the IP is not there.

I have these rules:

> sudo ufw status verbose

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip
```

**UPDATE**

Also, test from iptables

> iptables --policy INPUT DROP

I tried telnet for ssh, is blocking but for other services, I can still access them.

Any ideas? I don't want to create default deny for outgoing, and then whitelist every port I want.

**UPDATE**

The problem is that the services are running inside the container. If I create a new listener with nc the firewall is blocking that connection.

How can I block the incoming traffic for containers?

Comment: Did you test from another machine?

Comment: Yes, I test it from another PC also, with VPN. But still the port is open.

Comment: Can you describe what you tried in more detail?

Comment: I tried to block all the incoming traffic except from 2-3 IPs. But when i try to drop the input, same services they still listen. (Only ssh is really block)

Comment: How did you do that? If you block traffic from all IPs does it work as expected? ssh block might be due to the ssh config rather than firewall.

Comment: the problem is not the ssh, the problem is that i want to block all the incoming traffic but i can't. Other services still listen when i try to access them from NO WHITELIST IPs

Comment: Since your need looks, i suggest you use directly `iptables` instead of `ufw`....  I think you only need something like `iptables -P INPUT DROP`, `iptables -A INPUT -m state --ctstate RELATED, ESTABLISHED`, `iptables -i lo -J ACCEPT` and a bunch of `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport <yourport> -s <whitelisted ip> -j ACCEPT` to implement what you need.

Comment: thanks :) i will try to test the (second) answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383845/what-is-the-best-practice-of-docker-ufw-under-ubuntu?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because docker use also other Chains you have to block from DOCKER chain.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the host you want to blacklist has an IP address of 10.20.20.3

```
$ sudo ufw deny from 10.20.20.3 to any
$ sudo ufw reload
```